# Backup document root and MySQL in Linux

Tags: file, database, linux, server

I wrote this program to backup everything in document root and the MySQL database in Linux environments. It is aimed for Debian/Ubuntu environments to say the least.

```
zip -r /var/www/html/html-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip /var/www/html -x "*/cache/*"

mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > /var/www/html/db-$(date +\%F-\%T).sql
zip /var/www/html/db-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip /var/www/html/db-*.sql
rm /var/www/html/db-*.sql

zip -r /var/www/html/html-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip /db-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip /var/www/html/all_zipped.zip
rm -rf db-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip html-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip
```

I make the assumption that the document root is under `/var/www/html/`. In the past it was `/var/www/` but I don't think the change is going to be reverted or changed in the next 10 years...

Comment: Why do you do `zip -r /var/www/html/html-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip /db-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip /var/www/html/all_zipped.zip`?

Comment: This is to zip both the Dir zip and sql file inside one zip.

Comment: What is `all_zipped`?

Comment: All zipped is the file that includes the Dir zip and the sql zip.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the first argument of `zip` command?

Comment: You're right I confused.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: You probably don’t want to backup your dB into a world readable www root. Also the path to your dB.zips is specified differently in the various places.

Comment: Use double quotes around the filenames. the output of date should be very stable, but its still good practice and you may extend the date command with something more complicated in the future, which does not have such stable output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> zip -r /var/www/html/html-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip /var/www/html -x "*/cache/*"
> ```

You're making the backup directly available in your web root. For temporary files you should normally use `mktemp`.

NB I'm assuming that `/var/www/html` is not *directly* mapped to a `DirectoryRoot`: if it *is* visible, that's even worse.

---

> ```
> mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > /var/www/html/db-$(date +\%F-\%T).sql
> ```

Again, `mktemp`.

Secondly, this is interactive: `-p` requires you to be there to write the password. It might be more useful to have a script which could run with cron, although this would mean storing the password somewhere. In that case you should definitely create a new user with restricted rights who can dump the database but not change it.

Thirdly, experience has taught me to play it safe by adding `--hex-blob`. I have had difficulty restoring when this option was not used and encoding differences mangled the blobs.

---

> ```
> zip -r /var/www/html/html-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip /db-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip /var/www/html/all_zipped.zip
> ```

Yikes. If `zip` crashes for any reason you've just lost the old backup as well as the new one. I would prefer to have a `backups` directory (not under `/var/www/html`) and move `html-${TIMESTAMP}.zip` and `db-${TIMESTAMP}.zip` there. If you're worried about filling up your disk with backups, you can write a script to delete old ones.

A further advantage of having timestamped names is that you can identify the relative age of the offsite backups (you do have offsite copies, right?) without using `zip` to list the contents.

Comment: Thanks dearly Peter. I didn't understand what you mean here `If zip crashes for any reason you've just lost the old backup as well as the new one`.

Comment: Suppose `all_zipped.zip` contains `html-2018-01-03-13:00:00.zip` and `db-2018-01-03-13:01:31.zip` (the old backup). You run the script on 2018-01-10. When the script gets to that line, it overwrites `all_zipped.zip` (goodbye, old backup) and then crashes while adding `html-2018-01-10-13:00:00.zip`. The script continues, executes the `rm`, and exits. You have an `all_zipped.zip` which is useless. It's possible that I'm being overly pessimistic here and that `zip` doesn't touch the filesystem until it's finished writing the contents to disk, but I wouldn't want to take that risk.

Comment: I like that pessimism. I also don't know that. Is it good to cope with it? `zip -r /var/www/html/all_zipped-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip /var/www/html/html-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip /db-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip`

Comment: Yes, that avoids name clashes with the old backup. (Although I still prefer not to store it in `/var/www/html`, and to use variables as suggested by hjpotter92).

Answer (score 6):

Since you are repeatedly using `$(date +\%F-\%T)`, you can store that as a variable (unless you want to also know how long it took the script to jump between statements). Use that variable instead.

Similarly, set a basepath, which in your case, is `/var/www/html`. In case it changes in the future, it'll be just enough to change it in one place.

At the end, you have

```
rm -rf db-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip html-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip
```

which will try to delete those files from `CWD`, which might not be the same as `/var/www/html`.

`mysqldump` has options such as [`--compact`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_compact) and [`--compress`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_compress). Making use of them will result in smaller `sql` files, resulting in even smaller `zip`s; saving you some disk space.